# Case-sensitive regex that works

Tags: php, regex, case-sensitive

I have tried to change this regular expression to case-sensitive with a lot of possible solutions (`/[u=|&l=|&dl=|&f=]/i` and so on) but I didn't make it to work as I want to.

`u=`, `&l=`, `&dl=`, and `&f=` is taken from `profile-photos.php?u=edgren&dl=`. I use this regular expression to only get the username `edgren` and identify those other GETs (l, dl, and f) for example;

`Looking at <a href="'.url('user/'.$profile).'">'.properize($profile).'</a> '.(isset($_GET['l']) ? 'likes' : (isset($_GET['dl']) ? 'dislikes' : 'favorites'))` which prints "Looking at edgrens dislikes" with the URL `profile-photos.php?u=edgren&dl=`.

The regular expression I have now, prints `egren` ([example at regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28%5Bu%3D%7C%26l%3D%7C%26dl%3D%7C%26f%3D%5D%2B%29&input=u%3Dedgren%26dl%3D)) if the GET is &dl= which is wrong. I want to print the whole username and not the half of it, so to speak.

How can I fix my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, this would be [tag:php], then? If so, you might want to explicitly add that tag to your question.

Comment: Sorry :) My bad. Yes. It's for PHP.

Comment: First of all, if you want to match one of several strings, use round brackets: `(u=|&l=|&dl=|&f=)`. Square brackets are for characters classes (only single characters). Also `i` makes the regex case-**in**sensitive. Is that what you mean?

Comment: It seems to be doing what you're asking it to. But maybe I got something wrong. What exactly is the regex, and what is the string?

Comment: Is this what you want?: u=([^&]+)

Comment: Btw, PHP also has `parse_url()` and `parse_str()` for splitting up GET param strings.

Comment: m.buettner: Thanks for your correct answer :) It works like a charm now.

Comment: let me make that a proper answer then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing alternation with character classes. If you want to match one of several strings, use round brackets: `(u=|&l=|&dl=|&f=)`. Square brackets are for character classes (which have the meaning "match **one** character if it is one of those specified between these square brackets").

Also `i` makes the regex explicitly case-**in**sensitive.